# What am I doing wrong? unexpected unindent

Tags: python, indentation

I was testing an ARIMA Time Series Model in python, and ran into a "IndentationError: unexpected unindent" message. I've tried indenting and unindenting at several points to not avail. So I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Please see the code below, which leads to the following error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-64-8f9bf4ba4a44>", line 13
    results = mod.fit()
                       ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            
seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            
enforce_stationarity=False,

enforce_invertibility=False)
            
results = mod.fit()

print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, 
results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Keep the print statement and the line before it with proper indentation. In some IDE, try to convert all indentations to either spaces or tabs and recheck.

Comment: The entire `try:` block needs to be at the same level of indentation (to the right of the colon after `try`). The lines preceding are not flagging because it's inside a parenthetical expression, but the line throwing the error needs to be at the level of the code block it's in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is as clear as it can be : You have wrong indentation levels. Following works:

```py
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
                 y,
                 order=param,
                 seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                 enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False
            )
            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(
                 param,
                 param_seasonal,
                 results.aic
            ))
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: Confirming that your update solves the issue, and returns the desired results. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @DataExaminer Please accept the answer using the grey check mark on the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the try block, the try block should look this

```
    try:
        mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
             y,
             order=param,
             seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
             enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False
        )
        results = mod.fit()

        print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(
             param,
             param_seasonal,
             results.aic
        ))
    except:
        continue
```

Also would recommend using any modern IDE to eliminate indentation issues,

Comment: Dhinesh, thank you as well for the feedback. This definitely addresses the issue, and I will be employing a more modern IDE going forward.